# Carrierwave image dimension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, rmagick

How can I get the width and height of the current instance of carrierwave?

Something like this:

```
car_images.each do | image|
  image_tag( image.photo_url, :width => image.photo_width, :height => image.photo_height)
end
```

Unfortunately `image.photo_width` and `image.photo_height` are not working.
I need to specify the width and height of the images, it is required on the jquery plugin I'm using.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Combine https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Get-version-image-dimensions and https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Store-the-uploaded-file-size-and-content-type and you get:

```
class Image
  before_save :update_image_attributes

  private

  def update_image_attributes
    if image.present?
      self.content_type = image.file.content_type
      self.file_size = image.file.size
      self.width, self.height = `identify -format "%wx%h" #{image.file.path}`.split(/x/)
      # if you also need to store the original filename:
      # self.original_filename = image.file.filename
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 12):

You can save the height and width as attributes with your model quite easily if using Rmagick. In the Carrierwave uploader:

```rb
class ArtworkUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  def geometry
    @geometry ||= get_geometry
  end

  def get_geometry
    if @file
      img = ::Magick::Image::read(@file.file).first
      geometry = { width: img.columns, height: img.rows }
    end
  end

end
```

And in your model:

```rb
class Artwork < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :image, ArtworkUploader

  before_save :save_image_dimensions

  private

    def save_image_dimensions
      if image_changed?
        self.image_width  = image.geometry[:width]
        self.image_height = image.geometry[:height]
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: This works for new uploads (`image_changed?==true`) but what about measuring the dimensions of existing attachments? I can't seem to access `get_geometry` method from the console. I am getting "`private method 'file' called for #<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File:0x00000005225b28>`".

Answer (score 2):

Or just use [FastImage](https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage). This makes it much easier to measure attachments retroactively.

Comment: for just getting the dimensions, Fastimage is about a hundred times faster than Imagemagick

Answer (score 0):

@JamieD's answer worked for me, with one exception. I was using MiniMagick.

So I added something like this to my uploader.

```
def geometry
  @geometry ||= get_geometry
end

def get_geometry
  if @file
    img = ::Magick::Image::read(@file.file).first
    geometry = { width: img.columns, height: img.rows }
  end
end
```

Comment: I've updated https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Get-image-dimensions with MiniMagick info.